# Measuring Amplitude/Frequency of sound

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread, frequency

I need to read an analog signal at about 500-1000Hz for at least 5 seconds.

I've a battery powered microphone wired into an analog and ground pin on my arduino and am trying to measure the frequency (and amplitude) of sound coming from a rijke tube

To accurately represent the sound waves I need to take samples with a frequency at least twice that of the sound I'm studying, hence the frequency above. I plan to next do FFT to find the frequencies associated with the sound sample

Having stripped down every other part of my code, I could still only get at the most 107 readings a second, as shown below

```
#define VOLT_CAL 269
#define CURRENT_CAL 60
unsigned long time;

EnergyMonitor emon1;             // Create an instance

void setup()
{  
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("CLEARDATE");
  Serial.println("LABEL, DATE, TIME,Wall Voltage,Wall Current, Mic Voltage, Time Elapsed");
}

void loop()
{
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A4);

   time = millis();

  Serial.print(sensorValue);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(time); //prints time since program started
}
```

can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong/how I can increase the sample rate?

I've also tried to use a for loop to take my readings first, only printing them at the end but also maxed out at only 100 readings a second with the next attempt.

I've read also about preclocking, but the example codes were too complex for me to understand. A starting point in this direction would also be very much appreciated.

Comment: Serial prints at 9600 baud slow your loop down

Comment: i've tried it with 115200 and even 250000, it didnt get faster

Comment: 500 samples per second for 5 seconds with 16 bit integer = 5000 byte. The arduino uno has 2000 byte sram. Do you have another arduino board?

Comment: no...is it really complex to get maybe 400Hz? it doesn't need to be integers, i just need to read analog

Comment: Use a hardware timer, for example https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/50045/uniform-timing-when-using-arduino-for-data-acquisition .  Data sampling rates up to 100 kHz are possible!

Comment: Also, Arduino UNO can be used but to greatly increase the timing accuracy consider substituting the 16 MHz ceramic resonator for a crystal.

Comment: The arduino uno with the normal arduino functions can do 4000 samples per second. When using the registers of the microcontroller a higher sample rate is possible. Set the baudrate to 1000000, use only this in the loop (nothing else): Serial.println(analogRead(A4));

Comment: @Jot, there is a problem with your suggestion ..... there is no timing information in the resulting data

Comment: @zueses, is there a reason why you are using an arduino for this project?

Comment: it's just a starting suggestion from my professor, is it unreliable?

Comment: You need to do the engineering part first before doing a project like this. That is calculate possible sample rate, storage size, etc, given the resources. By doing this you can see that the given requirements cannot be met with an Arduino Uno. This might be what your professor actually wants you to do instead of implementing on an Arduino Uno just to find out it was not possible.